# DNS does not work over TCP from pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin, dnsmasq

I have an Openshift Origin installation (v. 1.2.1, but also reproduced this issue on 1.3.0), and I'm trying to get pods' IPs from DNS by service name. Assume my node has IP 192.168.58.6, and I look for pods of headless service 'hz' in project 'hz-test'. When I try to send DNS request to dnsmasq (which is installed on nodes and forwards requests to Kubernetes' SkyDNS) over UDP, everything goes well:

```
# dig +notcp +noall +answer hz.hz-test.svc.cluster.local @192.168.58.6  
hz.hz-test.svc.cluster.local. 14 IN A   10.1.2.5
<and so on...>
```

However, when I switch transport protocol to TCP, I receive the following error:

```
# dig +tcp +noall +answer hz.hz-test.svc.cluster.local @192.168.58.6  
;; communications error to 192.168.58.6#53: end of file
```

After looking on tcpdump output, I've discovered, that after establishing a TCP connection (SYN - SYN/ACK - ACK) dnsmasq immediately sends back FIN/ACK, and when the DNS client tries to send its request using this connection, dnsmasq sends back RST packet instead of DNS answer. I've tried to perform the same DNS query over TCP from the node iteself, and dnsmasq gave me usual response, i.e. it worked normally over TCP, and the problem arose only when I tried to perform request from pod. Also, I've tried to send the same query over TCP directly from pod to Kubernetes' DNS (avoiding dnsmasq), and this query was OK too.

So, why dnsmasq on nodes ignores TCP requests from pods, and why any other communications are okay? Is it supposed behavior?

Any help and ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, the reason was that dnsmasq was configured to listen node's IP (listen-adress=192.168.58.6). With such configuration dnsmasq binds to *all* node's network interfaces, but tries to reject "wrong" connections in userspace (i.e. on its own).

I don't really understand, why dnsmasq decided that requests from pod to 192.168.58.6 were forbidden with such configuration, but I got it working by changing "listen-address" to

```
interface=eth0
bind-interfaces
```

which forced dnsmasq to actually bind only to NIC with IP 192.168.58.6. After that dnsmasq started to accept all TCP requests.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this, as it saved us from a really significant bug we saw where DNS requests were failing in pods. We think that the TCP response was going to a different interface than the UDP request came from and that that's a bug in DNSMasq. But we can't be sure.

Comment: there was the same issue inside docker when accessing dnsmasq which was installed on the same host as the docker container. THANKS